# Nested Aggregation Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, nested, aggregation

I'm trying to build a nested aggregation in elasticsearch but it keeps giving errors. It says "cannot find agg type tags". How can I fix it. Thank you for your helps.Btw I don't have nested documents I have one document having 180 fields. Can I apply this aggregation? Here is my code:

```
{
  "aggs": {
     "comments": { 
      "nested": {
        "path": "comments"
      },
     "aggs" : {
    "red_products": {
      "filter": {
        "not": {
          "terms": {
            "text": [
              "06melihgokcek",
              "t.co","??","????","???"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_docs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "text",
            "size": 50
          }
        },

      "aggs" : {
            "tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "text",
                "include" : ".*avni.*",
                "exclude" : "fuat_.*"
            }
        }
    }
      }


    }
  }
}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your innermost `aggs` (the one called `tags` at the bottom) is misplaced and should be a child element of `top_docs`.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "comments": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "comments"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "red_products": {
          "filter": {
            "not": {
              "terms": {
                "text": [
                  "06melihgokcek",
                  "t.co",
                  "??",
                  "????",
                  "???"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_docs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "text",
                "size": 50
              },
              "aggs": {                   <---- this was the misplaced aggs
                "tags": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "text",
                    "include": ".*avni.*",
                    "exclude": "fuat_.*"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```